# can someone explain the usage or purpose of (char *) and (char **) when using malloc

Tags: c, pointers, casting, malloc

I'm following a tutorial at: http://www.learn-c.org/en/Arrays_and_Pointers

In the code they have:

```
// Allocate memory for nrows pointers
char **pvowels = (char **) malloc(nrows * sizeof(char));

// For each row, allocate memory for ncols elements
pvowels[0] = (char *) malloc(ncols * sizeof(char));
pvowels[1] = (char *) malloc(ncols * sizeof(char));
```

but if I remove the (char *) and (char **) it still works:

```
// Allocate memory for nrows pointers
char **pvowels = malloc(nrows * sizeof(char));

// For each row, allocate memory for ncols elements
pvowels[0] = malloc(ncols * sizeof(char));
pvowels[1] = malloc(ncols * sizeof(char));
```

The tutorial doesn't explain what this is, I'm assuming it is some sort of type casting, and maybe for this example it is not important to actually type cast it to work, rather the author thought it important to explicitly type cast.

Also I'm not familiar with what the double '*' is (**).

Just want to be sure I'm not missing anything and thank you for any explanation.

Comment: Get a better tutorial. Better: get a good C book; onlione tutorial are often bugged to the ceiling.

Comment: `char **` means a pointer to a pointer. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: The cast was needed for some C pre-1989.  It is not needed now.  Consider it optional, but unnecessary.

Comment: With or without the cast, `char **pvowels = malloc(nrows * sizeof(char));` is wrong... should be `sizeof(char *)`

Comment: Neither cast is required. There is NO need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) for thorough explanation.

Comment: Chux, Chris, and David, thanks for the tips. @Dmitri, an explanation of "why" is more important than that wrong/this right in my opinion...

Comment: @Discoveringmypath I thought the "why" would be obvious once the mistake was pointed out... you're allocating space for a bunch of `char`s, but what you *need* is space for a bunch of `char *`s (which are bigger).  So you need to fix the type in the `sizeof()` so that you calculate the right size for `malloc()` -- `nrows * sizeof(char)` is less than `nrows * sizeof(char *)`, and not enough space for `nrows` `char *`s.  Just for the line assigning to `pvowels`... the others really are allocating space for a bunch of `char`s, so they're fine.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, lack of experience with C. Thanks for the details!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The malloc function in your source code is allocating the amount of memory needed for the specific data type for your purposes (a char variable), the return used to have to be typecasted but not anymore, it's still a typical precaution.

a `char *` is a pointer to a variable of type char. a `char **` is a pointer to a pointer to a variable of type char.

I don't know how much about pointers has been explained to you, but you can think of a char pointer as the first char being referenced in a list of char variables. That's how strings are set up in memory, and a string is just a collection of char variables.

If you go a level deeper, you can have a char pointer *pointer*, which points to the first string being referenced in a list of strings. That is what the author is doing here, he is allocating the memory needed for an array of char pointers, and since each char pointer in this array itself points to a set of char values, they must each have memory allocated for them as well.

EDIT: To be more specific, these "lists" of things are called Arrays. A char array can be thought of as a string, and an array of char arrays can be thought of as a sentence.

Comment: The type has nothing to do with the amount of memory.

Comment: @Tyzoid It absolutely does. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm the data type is directly related to the amount of memory needed to store it in C

Comment: @RH6 the amount of memory *needed* might depend on data type, but the amount `malloc()` allocates has nothing to do with the type you cast its return value to, or the type of the pointer you assign it to.

Comment: @Dmitri I was speaking on what malloc was doing in the context of the OPs source code, not what malloc itself does, edited my answer a little for clarity.

Comment: It's just that the cast (in the OP's code or historically) didn't affect the amount of memory allocated.  It's just a matter of whether `void *` can be implicitly converted to another pointer type.

Comment: @Dmitri I understand, I've edited my answer to be a little more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very helpful and what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In the original K&R definition of the C language (pre-1989), the `*alloc` functions returned `char *`.  Because the language didn't (and still doesn't) allow assignments between incompatible pointer types, you had to explicitly cast the result to the target type if that type was not `char *`:

```
int *p;
...
p = (int *) malloc( n * sizeof (int) );
```

The 1989 standard introduced the `void *` type, which is an exception to the assignment rule above and serves as a "generic" pointer type - a value of `void *` may be assigned to *any* pointer type without need of an explicit cast, so as of the C89 standard,

```
p = malloc( n * sizeof (int) );
```

will work.

Note that this is *not* true in C++ - in that language, a `void *` value must be cast to the target type, so in C++ you would still have to write

```
p = (int *) malloc( n * sizeof (int) );
```

but if you're writing C++, you shouldn't be using `malloc` anyway.

Among most of us, it's considered a mistake to cast the result of `malloc`.  Under the C89 version of the language, you could actually introduce a bug by
doing so.  Under that version, if the compiler saw a function *call* without a declaration in scope, it would assume the function returned `int`.  So, if you somehow forgot to include `stdlib.h` and wrote

```
int *p = (int *) malloc( n * sizeof (int) );
```

the compiler would assume `malloc` returned an `int`.  Without the cast, this would result in an "incompatible types in assignment" diagnostic; however, including the cast would suppress the diagnostic, and you wouldn't realize there was an issue until you got a (sometimes very subtle and hard to diagnose) runtime problem.

That's no longer the case - the C99 revision of the language did away with implicit `int` declarations, so you'd get a diagnostic if you forget to include `stdlib.h`.

However, many of us feel that the cast adds an unnecessary maintenance burden (if you change the type of your target pointer, you have to update the cast as well), and IMO it makes code harder to read.

Why does the practice still persist in C?  Several reasons:

- The author started writing C code in the late 1970s/early 1980s and just never got out of the habit of using explicit casts;
- The author learned from out-of-date references or by reading very old code;
- The author wants to explicitly document the types involved.

Personally, I think the *right* way to write a `*alloc` call is

```
T *p = malloc( n * sizeof *p );
T *p = calloc( n, sizeof *p );
T *tmp = realloc( p, n * sizeof *p );
```

Clean, and if you ever change the type of `p`, you don't need to change anything about the `*alloc` call itself.

**EDIT**

> Also I'm not familiar with what the double '*' is (**).

Multiple indirection is possible in C - you can have pointers to pointers, pointers to pointers to pointers, etc.  For example, your `pvowels` object points to the first in a sequence of pointers to `char`:

```
         char **                  char *                         char
         -------                  -------                        ----
         +---+                    +---+                          +---+
pvowels: |   | -----> pvowels[0]: |   | ------> pvowels[0][0]:   |   | 
         +---+                    +---+                          +---+     
                      pvowels[1]: |   | ----+   pvowels[0][1]:   |   |
                                  +---+     |                    +---+
                                   ...      |                     ...
                                  +---+     |                    +---+
                    pvowels[r-1]: |   | --+ |   pvowels[0][c-1]: |   | 
                                  +---+   | |                    +---+
                                          | |
                                          | |                    +---+
                                          | +-> pvowels[1][0]:   |   |
                                          |                      +---+
                                          |     pvowels[1][1]:   |   |
                                          |                      +---+
                                          |                       ...
                                          |                      +---+
                                          |     pvowels[1][c-1]: |   |
                                          |                      +---+
                                         ...
```

Since `pvowels` points to the first of a sequence of pointers to `char`, its type must be "pointer to pointer to `char`", or `char **`.

When you `*alloc` memory for a sequence of objects of type `T`, the target pointer must have type `T *`:

```
T *p = malloc( n * sizeof *p );     // allocating a sequence of T
```

In the statement above, the *expression* `*p` has type `T`, so `sizeof *p` is equivalent to `sizeof (T)`.

If we replace `T` with a pointer type `P *`, it looks like

```
P **p = malloc( n * sizeof *p );    // allocating a sequence of P *
```

Instead of allocating space for a sequence of `P`, we're allocating space for a sequence of *pointers* to `P`.  Since `p` has type `P **`, the expression `*p` has type `P *`, so `sizeof *p` is the same as `sizeof (P *)`.

Note that in the `pvowels` case above, what you have is *not* a 2D array of `char`; `pvowels` points to the first of a sequence of pointers, each of which points to the first of a sequence of `char`.  You can index it *as though* it were a 2D array, but it's not structured like a 2D array; the "rows" are not adjacent in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Your answer is also right and I appreciate the extra info that you provided. I wish I would get responses this quick for Swift and SpriteKit!

Comment: @Discoveringmypath: Added a bit about the `**`.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` returns a `void *` pointer, which in newer versions of C can be assigned to any pointer type without explicit casting. This wasn't always the case, and is a historical artifact that has been often left in.

Comment: You mean "newer" to mean any standard compliant compiler released in the last 28 years?

Comment: @Rankin many people still compile c99, and some still on c89; this is especially true in older legacy codebases.

Comment: @Tyzoid If you subtract 28 from 2017, you get 1989 (e.g. C89) where the return of `malloc` was `void *` and where no cast was required to/from any other pointer type. **C89 Sect. 3.2.2.3 Pointers** *"A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object type."*

Comment: I apologize, that was the draft section, the Standard Section is **6.2.2.3**

Answer (score 0):

pvowels is of type char ** (a pointer to a character pointer(char* )). hence malloc(which returns void*) has to be casted to the "type" of pvowels.

If u remove char* in the sizeof function, it works cus that is what you want(that malloc reserves memory nrows the size of char type) that will probably hold the address of the char pointers.

if u remove the cast char **, my compiler throws an error, just as i'd expect(compiling in cpp). In c, it works just fine.

Comment: If removing the cast causes your compiler to throw an error, you're probably compiling as C++.  C doesn't require explicit casting between `void *` and other pointer types, but C++ does.

Comment: my bad. was coding in cpp when i saw question.